# Control startup order in Docker-Compose

Tags: docker, docker-compose, dockerfile

Is it possible to control the order of starting containers in Docker-compose beside the following method?

https://docs.docker.com/compose/startup-order/

```
version: "2"
services:
  web:
    build: .
    ports:
      - "80:8000"
    depends_on:
      - "db"
    command: ["./wait-for-it.sh", "db:5432", "--", "python", "app.py"]
  db:
    image: postgres
```

I have a container which depends on a redis databse container. However, it takes longer for redis to load in memory which causes the first container to exit. For now, I am using always restart method to deal with the problem as a workaround.

I was wondering if there is a better alternative as I would try to avoid the wait for it script?

Answer (score 6, accepted):

You can specify a healthcheck in your redis container and add `condition: service_healthy` to your `depends_on` field. This works since compose 2.1

```
version: "2.1"
services:
  web:
    build: .
    ports:
      - "80:8000"
    depends_on:
      "db":
        condition: service_healthy
    command: ["python", "app.py"]
  db:
    image: postgres
```

Detailed example of usage is here: https://github.com/peter-evans/docker-compose-healthcheck/blob/master/docker-compose.yml

Comment: Let me try this if it works and will get with the result.

Comment: Is there an equivelent for version 3? https://github.com/moby/moby/issues/30404#issuecomment-323212621

Comment: Version 3 no longer supports the condition form of depends_on

Answer (score 3):

By using the "depends_on" command in docker compose file, it is possible to change the starting order of the containers and give the priority to the containers which are needed to start early.

```
nginx:
    container_name: OTP-Nginx
    build: 
      context: ./nginx
      args:
        - comapanycode=${COMPANY_CODE}
        - dbtype=${DB_TYPE}
    ports:
      - "80:80"
    links:
      - db:db
    volumes:
      - ./nginx/octopus_nginx_params:/etc/nginx/octopus_nginx_params
     enabled/retail.octopusdashboard.com
      - /home/eleos/octopusupdates/DASHBOARDGLOBAL/branches-cdbwip:/var/www/${COMPANY_CODE}/cdb 
    depends_on:
      - db
```